# Find maxima for $f(x)=2/(1+(x^{d/u})^{(x-u)(x+1)^{a}})$, where $a$ is some constant

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, logarithms, maxima-minima

Who knows how to find the maxima for this function?

- $$f(x)=2/(1+(x^{d/u})^{(x-u)(x+1)^{a}}$$
- $a = -\ln(-((u - ku)\ln((ku)^{d/u}))/\ln(2/z - 1))/(ln(ku + 1))$

where $d, k, u, z$ are constants and

- $u>1,  1<z<2,  1/u<k<,  d>0$

[image: equation]
[image: graph]

You can experiment with the constants here:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5pgpbqywvj

An approximation I have found through randomizing the constants and doing curve fitting after using newtown's method looks like this:

$$(max_x) = 1.40507050224083 + 0.625438006773909 z log(u) + 0.174672097259909 z log(k)^{2} log(u) + 0.124047911240367 uz/(0.439620582483426 + d - d*k^{2}) - 0.690708328543431z$$

However, it is not accurate enough for my needs. In the image below the red dot represents max x. Overall it's the most accurate one but misses the mark for some combinations of constants. The curve looks quite predictable, and I think there should always be maxima within 1 < max x < u.

If there is an easier curve I can use which goes through (0,0), (1,1), (ku, z) and (u, 1) while looking like a skewed distribution or trapeze, then that might also be acceptable. Ideally, it would be great if the curve always had the same maximum, eg f(max x) = 2

Comment: I edited your question a little to use some MathJax. Please check if it is correct, and perhaps finish the job. You can get started [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/80734), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Fusion_Prog_Guy It boils down to finding the minimum of $g(x) = (x - u)(x + 1)^a \ln x$ for $1 < x < u$, right?

Comment: Thanks, Calvin Khor!

Comment: Yes, I believe so River Li.

Comment: River Li, how come you are multiplying by ln(x) though?

Comment: @Fusion_Prog_Guy min $x^{(d/u)(x-u)(x+1)^a} = \mathrm{e}^{(d/u)(x - u)(x + 1)^a \ln x}$? By the way, you may use @ in the comment, otherwise I do not receive notifications.